# How to disable a button if the input field not matches 10 digits

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation

I am very new to the UI part, i have one form which contains input type as number that field should accept only 10 digits only once the condition match i want to enable the submit button can you please help me did i miss anything ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pnum').on('keypress', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9\b]+$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        // for 10 digit number only
        if ($this.val().length > 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        if (e.charCode < 54 && e.charCode > 47) {
            if ($this.val().length == 0) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        }
        if (regex.test(str)) {
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
             return true;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail3">Phone Number</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">+ 91</span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="pnum" name="phone_number" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" maxlength="10" required>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" disabled id="submitButton" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-2">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail3">Phone Number</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">+ 91</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="pnum" name="phone_number" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" maxlength="10" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" disabled id="submitButton" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-2">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#pnum').on('keypress', function(e) {
           const value = e.target.value
           var $this = $(this);
           var regex = new RegExp("[0-9]{9}");
           // for 10 digit number only
           if (value.length > 9) {
               e.preventDefault();
               return false;
           }
           if (regex.test(value)) {
            $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
               return true;
           }
       });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: If you explain how your code works then the OP could learn something from your answer, as could other visitors in future.

Answer (score 0):

for disable and enable based on string length if its 10 than

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submitButton').prop('disabled', true);
$('#pnum').on('keypress', function(e) {
           var $this = $(this);
           if ($this.val().length == 10) {
               $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
           }else{
               $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', true);
           }     
  });

});
```